# Real time Object detection: where to learn?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I am working with opencv these days and I am capable of doing 99% of stuff explained in opencv official tutorials. And I managed to do motion tracking manually with background substraction, where some users claimed as impossible.

However, right now I am working with object detection, where I need to track the hand and want to find whether the hand is moved to left or right. Can this be done by following steps? (used in motion detection)

1. Get camera 2 instances of camera video (real time)
2. blur it to reduce noise
3. theresold it to find hand (or leave it if blur is enough)
4. find the absolute deference between 2 images
5. Get PSR
6. find pixel position of motion

However, it seems like it is not 100% same as motion detection, because I read some stuff about Kalman Filter, Block-matching, etc which I did not use in motion detection. However, I found this tutorial

http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece734/project/s06/lintangwuReport.pdf

But, I really need your advice. Is there any tutorial which teach me how to do this? I am interested in learning core theory with opencv explanation (c++).

Since I am not good at maths( I am working on it - I didnt go to the university , they found me and invited me to join the final year for free because of my programming skills, so I missed math) , full of math stuff will not work.

Please help. Thank you.